# Send MMS message using "HTTP Request" node

Tags: rest, n8n

I am trying to use n8n to send MMS message with Image.  How can I do that.  I believe n8n "twilio" node does not allow image.  I am trying to use "HTTP Request" node, but I am getting error. Please see image.  Can someone help me?

It connect fine with "GET" method and gets my status of the messages, but when I do "POST" to send the request it does not work (with or without image).  What am I doing wrong?

Use  "HTTP Request" node in n8n and send simple text at first.  then I would like to attach an image.

[image]